# How to create a velvet fabric material

Tags: materials, shaders

[image]

I have been looking at this painting for a while trying to recreate the red fabric material on his hat and poncho (not sure what the name is, but it looks like a poncho) from what i can tell it is some kind of velvet type material. I have found that a color ramp with layer weight as factor does provide an ok result to achieve the high lights effect. but I'm sure there must be better more realistic ways. Thanks in advance for any help! EDIT: this needs to be a shading setup that works in EEVEE.

Comment: did you try the velvet shader? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2211/how-exactly-does-the-sigma-parameter-affect-the-velvet-shader

Comment: sorry, i should have specified, i'm using eevee, so i need another way to recreate the material.

Comment: The velvet shader works on eevee too... but it would be kind of you if you shared an image of what you have and explained why you don't like it. I'd hate to suggest something you have tried already and don't like...

Comment: are you sure? because im using blender 2.8 and when i look at shaders i see no velvet shader. i need a shader that works in EEVEE render. not rendering using cycles.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQETR.png

Comment: what version are you using? i'm using the official 2.8 release and i dont have it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is something that I got to work pretty well. It is a lil on the complex side (sorry).

You could tweak the color ramps, sheen setting, and transmission to adjust the sheen to your liking.
Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the image in this velvet related post
[Is it possible to have group color input slider in Color Ramp Node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217819/is-it-possible-to-have-group-color-input-slider-in-color-ramp-node).

I have finally managed to make a procedural velvet shader for all purpose. Let me know if you want blend file for node group.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Please consider that this is no regular forum rather a Q&A site. Please add all relevant steps directly to your answer. If you'd like to share a file we prefer: https://blend-exchange.com/ Thanks.