# How to expose the hue of a Color Ramp node inside a node group?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm making a material in which the color in the Color Ramp Slider changes the color of the fabric material. Because I'm using noise texture to generate patches of 2 different colors, I'm unable to connect the slider color to group input. I tried looking for solution to add driver and it didn't work as intended.
[image: Node Group]

Update: Thanks to moderator for re-opening the thread. I have already seen the link provided by PGmath. The method in the link basically says "This is workaround" and it's bit on complex side. I don't mind playing with math modes to achieve the desired result. But that too doesn't seem to work in my case. The link explains how you can get node group that behaves like Colorramp. What I want is a node input for changing color hue. Anyways, thank you guys for helping out. Got a workaround fiddling with MIXRGB and Math node that achieves what I'm looking for.

Below are the images of the result.
[image: Inside Shader Node Tree]

BTW, if you guys have been wondering I'm making a procedural Velvet Shader.
[image: Procedural Velvet Shader]

Comment: Does an approach like what is [shown here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40829/5705) for making a homemade color ramp node work for you?

Comment: Yes sure, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yea that what I was talking about. I tried that and it doesn't help here. You can add driver for pos but not for slider. There's no such option in right click context menu.

Comment: I edited the name of the dupe question to better reflect what the question was going for (drivers did not end up being necessary to accomplish the desired task).

Comment: Why not just use the Hue value to change the color? It's not an RGB color but should do the trick?

Comment: @Blunder I think it's a brilliant idea. I can add one more hue/sat in between color ramp and principled bsdf and connect both of the hue/sat to group input. Will try and reply back.

Comment: @PritamRaya I'm confused, I don't quite understand the obstacle you encountered with PGmath's answer in the other question. I've re-opened your question in the meantime but could you elaborate more on how that answer doesn't do what you want? It should work without any drivers, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Glad you figured something out! If you'd like, could you post your solution and mark it as accepted in the answer section down below? That way anyone with the same question in the future will be able to find it more easily :) I've also gone ahead and tweaked your question title a little, feel free to roll back my changes if you don't agree with them.

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks for the feedback but I'm not quite sure if this would help people to solve the issue by exposing the hue of a Color Ramp node inside a node group. Because the end solution doesn't exactly inhere the ColorRamp node at all in the node tree, but a mix of Math Node and MIXRGB. Neither my original title is correct. I think the whole thing took a different route to get to the destination. So at this point I'm not sure what title would be suitable for this. And ye you can close the thread since I found the solution. Also huge thanks to you all fellas trying to solve this for me.

Comment: @pritamraya Thanks for your patience! That's fair enough, I've marked as a duplicate again so the banner at the top makes the other question as visible as possible.