# Is there a way to allow colorramp silder color to have group input group?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I already asked this question here.
[Is it possible to have group color input slider in Color Ramp Node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217819/is-it-possible-to-have-group-color-input-slider-in-color-ramp-node?noredirect=1#comment367457_217819)

That's exactly what referring to, and yes I tried that and it doesn't help here. You can add driver for pos but not for slider. There's no such option in right click context menu.

You can't close the thread simply without any testing. Referring to other similar topic? Did you even tested yourself what I'm trying to achieve? if so then your link provide no help to me.

Comment: Sorry to read that your question was closed as duplicate and the linked solution does not work for you. But mistakes can happen. You can flag the question with "in need of moderator intervention" and an admin can re-open it.

Comment: @Blunder. Thanks for suggestion, will flag for sure.